# Xcode will not open the Main.storyboard file

Tags: macos, xcode

I had been running Xcode to learn to develop ios Apps. All was working fine but Xcode kept freezing and I'd half to force quit. It was suggested I reintall Xcode. I did that and it seemed to reinstall fine.

Now, however, Xcode launches but it won't open the Main.storyboard file.  It opens and you can edit the text files but when I try to open Main.storyboard, or LaunchScreen.storyboard, a gear-like icon starts turning but it never loads a file.

Can someone please help me get Xcode working.

I'm running High Sierra 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.1.

Here is the source code for Main.storyboard

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="ygV-oz-tLR">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--ToDo List-->
        <scene sceneID="A9s-AT-4j0">
            <objects>
                <tableViewController id="yR9-hP-vAV" customClass="ToDoTableViewController" customModule="ToDo_List" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <tableView key="view" clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" id="Ixa-rN-v7n">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <prototypes>
                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="ngh-G9-ONg">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="375" height="44"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="ngh-G9-ONg" id="cWC-8W-qDK">
                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="43.5"/>
                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                            </tableViewCell>
                        </prototypes>
                        <connections>
                            <outlet property="dataSource" destination="yR9-hP-vAV" id="cpa-VR-las"/>
                            <outlet property="delegate" destination="yR9-hP-vAV" id="PVd-rM-Yqu"/>
                        </connections>
                    </tableView>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" title="ToDo List" id="1K6-Q0-zG0">
                        <barButtonItem key="rightBarButtonItem" systemItem="add" id="fBK-eZ-L90">
                            <connections>
                                <segue destination="xmu-tN-ZMm" kind="show" id="aVw-WO-sTe"/>
                            </connections>
                        </barButtonItem>
                    </navigationItem>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="B4l-Zb-T9m" kind="show" identifier="moveToComplete" id="b7Q-gS-cwz"/>
                    </connections>
                </tableViewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ILe-S0-MPF" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1610" y="-429"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Create To Do View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="crg-nJ-Vb3">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="xmu-tN-ZMm" customClass="CreateToDoViewController" customModule="ToDo_List" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="k2t-ln-joT">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Task" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="QMa-uF-UB2">
                                <rect key="frame" x="164" y="95" width="47.5" height="29"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" borderStyle="bezel" placeholder="Buy Eggs" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZJ9-HW-zPC">
                                <rect key="frame" x="25" y="132" width="325" height="34"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                            </textField>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Important?" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NCJ-uw-GE1">
                                <rect key="frame" x="131" y="205" width="113" height="29"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lQa-iU-USM">
                                <rect key="frame" x="163" y="244" width="51" height="31"/>
                            </switch>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="QLZ-dz-gZY">
                                <rect key="frame" x="166" y="313" width="43" height="41"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Add"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="addTapped:" destination="xmu-tN-ZMm" eventType="touchUpInside" id="OwY-gs-dRH"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="QMa-uF-UB2" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PUs-XU-5Va" secondAttribute="top" constant="31" id="50H-Kd-uRn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZJ9-HW-zPC" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="k2t-ln-joT" secondAttribute="centerX" id="61r-ue-1mo"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QLZ-dz-gZY" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="k2t-ln-joT" secondAttribute="centerX" id="BN6-mZ-rwD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QMa-uF-UB2" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="k2t-ln-joT" secondAttribute="centerX" id="J9w-Ou-EWI"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NCJ-uw-GE1" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="k2t-ln-joT" secondAttribute="centerX" id="MZY-e1-lOr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="lQa-iU-USM" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="k2t-ln-joT" secondAttribute="centerX" id="bNr-NW-ddD"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZJ9-HW-zPC" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="PUs-XU-5Va" secondAttribute="leading" constant="25" id="hue-hV-lLs"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="lQa-iU-USM" firstAttribute="firstBaseline" secondItem="NCJ-uw-GE1" secondAttribute="baseline" constant="16" symbolType="layoutAnchor" id="kUT-Zs-1gg"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NCJ-uw-GE1" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZJ9-HW-zPC" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="39" id="oQo-Uu-0Qp"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="PUs-XU-5Va" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ZJ9-HW-zPC" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="25" id="oTN-xi-wpK"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="QLZ-dz-gZY" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="lQa-iU-USM" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="38" id="tMz-0b-mL3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZJ9-HW-zPC" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="QMa-uF-UB2" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="xrJ-dT-oA7"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="PUs-XU-5Va"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="ImportantSwitch" destination="lQa-iU-USM" id="KcW-b1-3iy"/>
                        <outlet property="nameTextfield" destination="ZJ9-HW-zPC" id="Dbd-lL-UYg"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="XVC-FI-qmt" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="2302" y="-429"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Complete View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="J4s-0m-7oZ">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="B4l-Zb-T9m" customClass="CompleteViewController" customModule="ToDo_List" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="gIE-qm-ziM">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="3" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VlY-OE-5rH">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="100" width="335" height="29"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="L1s-7S-g1r">
                                <rect key="frame" x="137" y="135" width="101" height="41"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="24"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Complete"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="completeTapped:" destination="B4l-Zb-T9m" eventType="touchUpInside" id="Kqw-Fe-o6g"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="VlY-OE-5rH" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="gIE-qm-ziM" secondAttribute="centerX" id="NQb-3P-0Bh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="q5f-nc-a7m" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="VlY-OE-5rH" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="O1n-Kd-5aL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="L1s-7S-g1r" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VlY-OE-5rH" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="6" id="PEm-nv-co8"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="VlY-OE-5rH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="q5f-nc-a7m" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="bTf-XD-FK3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="L1s-7S-g1r" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="gIE-qm-ziM" secondAttribute="centerX" id="fev-Xl-h5r"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="VlY-OE-5rH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="q5f-nc-a7m" secondAttribute="top" constant="36" id="iay-D9-tWA"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="VlY-OE-5rH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="q5f-nc-a7m" secondAttribute="top" constant="36" id="t6F-85-2uY"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="VlY-OE-5rH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="q5f-nc-a7m" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="tEY-Zk-8tN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="q5f-nc-a7m" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="VlY-OE-5rH" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="tFS-fF-mSN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="L1s-7S-g1r" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="VlY-OE-5rH" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="6" id="xDx-fv-OjJ"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="q5f-nc-a7m"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="nameLabel" destination="VlY-OE-5rH" id="R1V-mk-y6s"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="uVo-zX-Ks5" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1609" y="385"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="boR-hX-Jev">
            <objects>
                <navigationController id="ygV-oz-tLR" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="SFC-Nc-Db8">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="yR9-hP-vAV" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="Z7o-NW-Xqp"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="urB-J8-cVw" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="658" y="-429"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: What happens if you create new Project and try to open the storyboard there?

Comment: Same thing. i tried that earlier. Can't open Main.storyboard.

Comment: Can you right click on a storyboard, open it as a source code and paste the `<device>` and `<dependencies>` sections as part of your question?

Comment: I copied the source code and pasted it in my question.

Comment: i'll be happy to do anything else if I can,

Comment: Did you try deleting the contents of the Derived Data folder?  When Xcode isn't running, delete that folder contents and then restart Xcode.  Sometimes that helps.

Comment: @fsb that won't help if the storyboard is not opening even on the newly created Project. jmh I can't see the edited question with the pasted code.

Comment: @fsb  where is derived darafolder.  i tried a different way of displaying contents of Main.storyboard file. Can you read it now?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek  i tried a different way of displaying contents. Does that help?

Comment: Try [this info](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Fixing-Xcode).

Comment: It opens fine in my Xcode, maybe try to change the device line to `<device id="retina4_0" orientation="portrait">` It'll try to render it for iPhone SE.

Comment: i have an old 2010 iMac. Does that affect my device id?

Comment: THAT WORKED!!!  or it seems to have worked. At least when I click on that particular main.storyboard it shows what looks like a storyboard...

Comment: I got excited too early. When I start xcode I get a warning that says: "An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited".  And I can't open the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

Comment: So it looks like the rendering of the storyboard using "iPhone 8" layout is broken. I'm not sure how to change the "device" for all storyboards. Maybe after opening the Main.storyboard and then creating new project the device is somehow saved.

Comment: I’ll try that as soon as I get back to my computer. Thanks.

Comment: @fsb  I tried your suggestion about the derived_data file and it didn't work the first time. I may have entered something wrong.  I tried it  again now and it seems to have worked!! I deleted contents of the /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData file and then restarted my computer. That seems to have solved the problem.  Thank you for your suggestion!  I was very concerned I wasn't going to get this fixed.  You have saved me from pulling out what hair I have. I know you don't need the points but if you want to write this as a short answer I will select it.

Comment: Well, I got it fixed. I tried fsb's suggestion again and it seemed to work this time.  I opened the /Users/xxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder and deleted the contents.  Then I restarted my computer. Thank you very much for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you.  It's a hit-or-miss answer/solution which is why it's one of the first things I try when I'm having weird Xcode issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source 1](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Fixing-Xcode)
[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42760524/3487310)

There's several things that can wrong with `.storyboard` files.  This is not the only solution to these issues so YMMV.  From experience I've found that that cleaning the build folder and/or clearing the **Derived Data** folder are quick & easy first steps in troubleshooting.

### Clean Build Folder

In Xcode, open a code window.  Go to the `Product -> Clean Build Folder` menu command (or use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>).

### Delete Derived Data

In macOS 10.12 and later, this folder should be automatically cleared.  Sometimes, manually deleting the files located here will force Xcode to rebuild them, solving some common issues.  There's several ways to do almost the same thing:

1. Terminal

   - Close Xcode.
   - In Terminal, run this command: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
2. In the Xcode Project

   - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> will delete the folder for that project.
3. In the Xcode Project

   - Go to `File -> Project Settings` for a Project, or `File -> Workspace Settings` for a Workspace
   - Click the arrow behind the path to go directly to the Derived Data folder
     [image]
   - Close Xcode
   - Delete the contents (subfolders) in the Derived Data folder